# Electron + React keeps reload the page when fs.writeFileSync()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

preload.js

```
const { readFile, readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs')
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, ipcMain } = require('electron')
require('electron')
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('config', {
    readConfig: () => {
        const data = readFileSync(__dirname + '/config.json', 'utf-8')
        return data
    },
    writeJson: (data) => {
        writeFileSync(__dirname + '/config.json', data)
    },

    ipc: ipcRenderer,
})
```

React App.js

the function that causes Electron refresh

```
    const onNoteAdd = () => {
        const newNote = {
            description: '',
            id: Noteid,
        }
        const newArr = arr.concat(newNote)
        writeJson(JSON.stringify(newArr))
        setArr(newArr)
        setNoteId((Noteid) => Noteid + 1)
    }
```

Electron.js

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    createWindow()
    const ipc = ipcMain
    ipc.on('message', (event, data) => {
        console.log(data)
        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/config.json', data)
    })
})
```

I want to overwrite the JSON in the public folder with the one that ipcMain received from the ipcRender in App.js

But the problem is that when writeFileSync works,

somehow electron gets refreshed and overwritting is skipped

I tried to overwrite with 'writeJson' function in preload.js file with App.js and using ipc.send in App.js and receive in Electron.js and write the json, but nothing worked.

Electron version is 12.0.7

Answer (score 1):

you probably have hot reload enabled, try add an ignore path

**electron-reloader**

`require('electron-reloader')(module, {ignore: [regex_to_config_json]})`

**electron-reload**

`require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {ignored: [regex_to_config_json] })`